# Autodesk Forge: Industrial Construction Demo bucket not working

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, forge, demo

I have cloned the Industrial Construction Demo code https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-industrial-construction but I am having issues with the 'bucket-name'.

In the launch file you need to specify  "FORGE_BUCKET": "" instead of the usual URN.

I have written the name of the bucket that contains my file but it does not work. I have tried debugging it but still no luck.

There is no exemplary bucket or files, so I would really like to know:

-What do I need to put in as the bucket name?

-What files need to be in the bucket?

-What file types?

-Any extra information to help me figure out why it isnt working.

Many thanks,
Poppy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, I haven't explained this in the code sample very well. The demo requires files in Forge to be named in a specific way. I have just updated the README with more details: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-industrial-construction.